# Spi based pin expander for Arduino

Tags: arduino-ide, pins

I don't have enough pins on my Esp32 board. I would like to use a pin expander. All the ones I could find online only use i2c. Are there ones available that use SPI?

I would like send pwm signals to the pin expander outputs. Is that possible?

Comment: Pin extenders for when you don't have enough pins on your board.

Comment: @Juraj what do you call this https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/MCP23S17

Comment: @Juraj I need to use the pins simultaneously. Multiplexers can only output through one pin at a time.

Comment: @NadimAhmed I do those chips in pairs on a breakout board: https://majenko.co.uk/expander32.php

Comment: @NadimAhmed The MCP23017 GPIO expander chips are digital only; ie., they can NOT do PWM.

Comment: @stevieb thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/MCP23S17. Found it. I am gonna leave this here in case anyone needs it.

Comment: I assume you will still have problems sending "pwm signal**s** to these pin extender pins"